# How to animate any icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation

As you may know, there exists not only an '''Icons''' class in flutter, but also an '''AnimatedIcons''' class. For example I already used '''AnimatedIcons.pause_play'''

I want an animated mute icon. I imagined something like on Youtube when you mute there. But I cant find anything like that. Does anybody knows if there is a package with free to use animated icons? Or do I have to build my own animated icon? (if so, please give me a little hint, how to do that.)

Thank you.

I already researched for "flutter make own animated icons" on google, but i just found a side whrere they used the Icons from the AnimatedIcons class. And i can not find a mute icon in there. I was more expecting a tutorial on how to animate any item.
So that was no use. Of course I also searched for packages with more animated icons, but I coulnt find any.